# NPX create-react-app cannot find a matching version for @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@2.19.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, npx

I'm on a new computer and tried to run `npx create-react-app myapp` and I am receiving this error. Never had this before, it looks like it's missing the es-lint package?

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 99 in 4.157s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Name\Documents\demos\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@2.19.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-10T19_41_06_770Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Name\Documents\demos
Done.
```

Comment: try running `npm install -g create-react-app` and then try creating a project

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is now a known bug in the release of typescript-eslint version 2.19.1 a couple hours ago and they're working on fixing it at the moment:

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1588

UPDATE:
This was a problem with NPM - and there were likely other builds affected. 
https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/1dpd0zjyhj2v

Either way, this has been resolved.

Comment: I don't think it is resolved yet: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8998